# Error when save BitmapImage to Local folder Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I have BitmapImage (downloaded from live sdk output), and i do following code to save to local folder

```
var rass = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri(photoResultdyn.location, UriKind.Absolute));
var stream = await rass.OpenReadAsync();

var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
```

And use WritableBitmap to convert bitmapImage to a WritableBitMap image.

```
WritableBitmap wbm = new WritableBitmap(bitmapImage);
```

but failed.

any solutions ?

**I am using Windows Phone 8.1 (In Universal App Solution)**

Comment: Universal apps only work on Windows 10 Mobile, as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

The WriteableBitmap(BitmapImage) constructor is for Silverlight. It is not available to Windows Runtime apps.

To save your stream to disk along with adding it to a BitmapImage, you can save the original stream that you create the BitmapImage directly to disk. This will avoid decoding and reencoding the bitmap, which (depending on the image file format) may be lossy.

If the save is far enough away from the download that you don't have the stream then you can avoid converting from BitmapImage by using a WriteableBitmap to begin with. Both are [BitmapSources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.bitmapsource.aspx) and can be used interchangeably in most situations.

```
var bitmapImage = new WriteableBitmap();
bitmapImage.SetSource(stream);
```